# MySQL - Output of last select in procedure with update and insert

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

I have a stored procedure that executes the following statements:

1. A select to populate a variable
2. An update utilizing said variable
3. Another select to populate a second variable
4. An insert using the second variable
5. A select of last_insert_id() to spit out 4's insert ID to the calling application.

The SP is returning the first variable, since it is the first select.

Is there any way I can retrieve that last insert id, instead?

I know I could use the last insert id on my application's cursor, but that breaks a model I'm using. I suppose I could do that as a last resort, but I'm searching for additional options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUPUT parameter in your stored procedure storing value of last insert id.